# Get S3 bucket name assocaited with a lambda function using aws lambda sdk

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

i have a lambda function created using the existing blueprint "s3-get-object".

Using the aWS lambda java sdk, i am trying to get the s3 bucket name associated with the lambda function.

I used LambdaAsyncClient.listFunctionEventInvokeConfigs(...) method, but that did not help. Please advice how to achieve this

Comment: Not familiar with the blueprint but if you are looking for the s3 object notification config that triggers the lambda you need to check s3, not the lambda.

Comment: Are you saying that you have an AWS Lambda function that is being triggered automatically when a new object is uploaded to an Amazon S3 bucket? What are you actually wanting to achieve (_what_, not _how_)?